# Zener diode + transistor circuit

Tags: transistors, diodes, zener

[image]

I need to turn off an LED when the voltage reaches 10V. My source is maximum 12.8V (three lithium batteries.) The (yellow) LED is rated 2.1V and 30mA forward current, but the resistor I chose is 3.3k because I need it dim and low consumption. When powered directly from the source, it marked 2.84mA @ 11.16v. Also 0.033mW.

The Zener diode is rated 10V 500mW.

I tried different values for the diode resistor and the one that came closest to producing the same overall 2.84mA current (and LED intensity) was 11k.

I don't know why and couldn't find a formula that explains my result. The transistor's measured Hfe is 140.

I would really appreciate if someone could explain me a bit of the theory behind, since I need to replicate the circuit under different conditions.

Comment: When you say "diode resistor" do you mean the **zener** diode resistor?  An LED is also a diode.

Comment: This circuit will turn the LED **on** when the supply reaches around 10.6 V (10 V zener diode + Vbe of the transistor). *I don't know why and couldn't find a formula that explains my result* Circuits aren't defined by formulas. You need to think in terms of: when the voltage reaches 10 V, can the zener diode conduct? No because there's also a Vbe of the PNP. Only when that Vbe is larger than 0.6 V will any current flow through the Emitter-Base. What will happen when when current flows through the Emitter-Base of the PNP? Again: no formulas!

Comment: Thank you Bimpelrekkie, I'll try to think that way and now I understand actually why the zener was not cutting at 10v exactly but almost 11v. Appreciated. But still, given the case of a diode with a 3.3k resistor (per schematic), how can you know the appropriate base (zener) resistor value for it? So no power is dissipated and the same power arrives to the led? I figured it out at 11k trying different values with a potentiometer, but how can one know in advance?

@TimWescott I meant the zener diode resistor (see diagram).

Comment: Here is another question about a circuit with a similar function: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/547417/how-to-improve-this-battery-status-voltage-monitor-circuit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you plan to use a zener, then the key idea to hold in your head is that the zener will *start* conducting when sufficiently reverse-biased. You also need to keep in your mind that you'll need a series, current-limiting resistor to protect the zener as well as to operate it at the correct (datasheet) current (which varies depending on the zener's nameplated voltage.)

So, you have two parts in mind now. Just use your imagination about how to keep a transistor off when there's no current and then on when there is current. That's the only problem to solve in your mind.

A BJT transistor is on when it's \$V_{\text{BE}}\$ is forward-biased, sufficiently. It's off, otherwise. (That's a gross simplification, but so long as you imagine "less than \$400\:\text{mV}\$ means off and more than \$550\:\text{mV}\$ it is starting to be on" then you won't be too far afield.)

Hmm. If the zener conducts then there must be a voltage drop across that current-limiting resistor. And if not, then there will be no voltage drop across it. Sounds like a fit -- maybe, anyway.

So what about:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxrr2b.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

It almost looks okay. Using the overly-simplistic argument I just made, this circuit looks like it may work well. When the zener is 'on' then there will be a voltage drop across \$R_1\$ and that should turn on the BJT. And it does. So, technically, it will turn on the LED at "some determined voltage," now.

The problem with it (well, the bigger problem anyway) is that once on and as the supply voltage rises still further then the BJT base will start supplying insane levels of current into the zener. That will probably not comport with your:

> I need it ... low consumption

So, another cheap idea is to just move the LED resistor to the other side of the BJT. That should limit the ability of the BJT base to jam current into the zener, because the emitter resistor will be in the way of it.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9CSNk.png)</sup>

Now, if you try this arrangement, it will much better meet your requirement as well as turning the LED on at a particular threshold.

The problem with this arrangement is that now it is a voltage-dependent current source to the LED. Let's say \$R_1=R_2=1\:\text{k}\Omega\$. Then the max LED current will be about \$2\:\text{mA}\$. But that LED current will decline *linearly* with lower voltages. So the brightness will be less when the voltage is less. This may be acceptable. I cannot say.

But the point of the above is to use your imagination and just think, a little. Turn things over in your head in different ways.

Here's another simple approach that minimizes the voltage-dependent current source period and makes it more of an on/off circuit -- through it still has its "behaviors."

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2faxfdk.png)</sup>

That might perform acceptably. Now, \$R_1\$ sets the LED current and because this is a voltage-independent current source (once sufficient voltage overhead is reached), it behaves more like on/off than the earlier circuit.

These aren't by any means the only ideas that come to mind. There are countless ways to do this. For example, the very first thing I may want to do for a low power unit is to avoid the zener. You already may only want about \$1\:\text{mA}\$ or maybe \$2\:\text{mA}\$ in the LED. That's bad enough. You don't want to have to waste about the same amount (or still more) when feeding a zener diode. So you may want to look for a lower-current "zener-like" circuit for the voltage comparison part of this circuit.

You cannot do anything much about the LED, except to buy as high-efficiency LED as possible. But once that's decided, you are stuck with its requirement. The only thing left is to worry about the voltage comparison part. And much can be done on that front.

For example, Diodes Inc has the [AP431S](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/AP431S.pdf), which is very low current (tens of microamps) and can be set to a desired voltage, as well.

In addition, BJTs require recombination currents. These can be quite modest -- absolutely no more than 10% but can be 1% or so. And that isn't usually a big deal. But a FET can use even less. So if you get to the point of really wanting to squeeze the last few current-pennies out of the circuit, then you might consider using more expensive FETs and modifying the design once again.

Comment: A mind opener jonk... brilliant. but how to decide the value of R1 in your first two examples? given that I want the led to receive 2.84mA @ 11.16v? I ask because I also want to turn on a relay (45ohm) instead of a led, but can't figure out the base resistor value when a zener is involved.

Comment: @Domingo Then you don't want a constant current circuit. You want a switch circuit for the relay. That's a different thing. Did I miss it? Or did you fail to include this requirement in your original question?

Comment: I failed to include the requirement in the original question, because I assume that a relay would work the same way than a led, ie. when the transistor is closed current flows through the collector-emitter junction and bias the coil of the relay. I don't see the difference with a circuit where a led or a relay is turned on; as long as the transistor is closed, once the base is charged via the zener. Probably I'm missing out something.

Comment: @Domingo The LED has an exponential response to voltage and therefore requires some means of limiting the current. Besides, an LED's brightness is linearly related to its current. So the current in an LED is what everyone cares about. A relay is basically a coil. And you cannot jam a current into a coil. Just doesn't work like that. A relay requires a minimum voltage to engage and then a different voltage to hold, once engaged, and when released there is a significant kick-back voltage they generate that has to be accommodated. These are about as different as night and day.

Comment: @Domingo In general, it's just good advice that you write the truth about what you are doing. Even those of us who know enough to replace one thing with another, as a valid simplifying equivalent, have enough sense to state what we are doing and why we are doing it. It's perfectly fine to replace a circuit that is only a modest approximation of a current source with an ideal current source if the difference doesn't matter to the question and if using the simpler, idealized form makes it easier for others to focus on the section where the question is at.

Comment: @Domingo But we do that from ***knowledge*** and we still tell others we are doing that, and why. Because we may miss something important. So the context is still important. So even when we know what we are doing, we disclose everything anyway.

Comment: @Domingo This is why you should not presume and replace one thing with another. Especially when you are just learning things. When you make decisions about "this is equal to that" then you are claiming to have specific knowledge that these things are equivalent. If you aren't absolutely certain you are right in doing so, then write as much of the situation as you can and don't make replacements when you are not competent to do so. You are kind of shooting yourself in the foot, so to speak, when you assume you know more than you do.

Comment: Good basic considerations. I was planning to use two stages of the same circuit, one for an LED low-battery voltage indicator (at a certain zener value), the second one to activate a relay that would break the circuit at the source (to avoid further draining of the batteries). Maybe I should have formulated my question this way originally, but if any simple approach to achieve these (two) things comes to the mind I'll be ready to study/implement them.

Comment: @Domingo Okay. So you have an answer that may help with the LED. I'd recommend that you write up another one -- this time referring to this question regarding the LED as a base reference for context, and then writing up a new question that asks about having a single circuit for a "voltage comparison" that drives two circuits -- one for an LED and one for a relay that should operate at the same time. (If that's what you mean.) If on the other hand you want two different voltage comparisons, one for the LED and one for the relay, then just ask about the relay itself.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I'll leave the relay for another question and stick to the LED circuit here. Sorry for presuming things. For the LED circuit, any word on the value of R2? I'm confused because it seems to have the double purpose of limiting the zener current and determining the base current for the base to "charge". I don't know if it should be calculated according to the maximum current of the zener: Rs=(Vs-Vz)/Iz. Or in relation to the load and the Hfe of the transistor: Rs=(Vs-Vz)/(Lc/Hfe). Or both, or non and this has nothing to do with mathematics (at the moment)?

Comment: @Domingo Are we discussing the last circuit? Because I don't think the first one is worth a darn and the second one is a voltage-dependent current source so the LED brightness will vary on the voltage above 10 V. You haven't said if that's okay or if you'd rather go with the final version (which does have values.) If you want to try the middle schematic, perhaps try 1k for both resistors and see if that 'feels okay' to you. There is math to it. Are you looking to work that out?

Comment: Yes please, if you could share some of it with me. But I'm actually thinking of your second example, because of its simplicity and brightness variations are desirable for me since they give extra indication on the battery status. It should however cut at 10v, so maybe I'll use a 9.1v zener to account for the -0.7 Vbe.

Comment: Jonk: *... then the BJT base will start supplying insane levels of current into the zener*. Yes, with supply voltage above about 10.6V in circuit #1, enough current flows to kill the transistor base-emitter junction - I'd guess base-emitter fail before the zener fails. I'd not want someone to try this version.

Comment: @glen_geek Yeah. I didn't write it that way, but when writing I certainly was thinking about the fact that the BJT would likely die in the process. I'd have to burn up a few to be sure. But I can't see them surviving many 100's of mA.

Comment: @Domingo Just make sure you have a high efficiency LED and try out the 1k resistors I mentioned. There isn't a precision *knee* to that circuit, so what matters is what you can see and like seeing. That's going to be a fairly personal choice. So if you have a few different zeners (recommended) you can try out different values.

Comment: Thanks a lot again for your contributions Jonk.